# Wix rollback custom action not work in upgrade cancel

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

i dont know why the rollback action not work in upgrade process,But it work in install process,i have tried almost all the method i found in the google,i really hope i can find the answer here,So my question is :
1.We must define two custom action?one is deferred,another is rollback,and rollback must be before the deferred? **but my rollback action just want to restart the service when the upgrade fail,** so it is necessary to do this?and i have tried this method,it not work,but it work in install that i just defined a rollback action,you can see as the follow:( **rollback action is between in InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize**)

1.in InstallExecuteSequence

```
  <Custom Action="StartAllServicesWhenRollBack" After="InstallInitialize">1</Custom>
  <Custom Action="UninstallMysqlOdbcDriver" After="StartAllServicesWhenRollBack">1</Custom>
```

2.in Fragment

```
<CustomAction Id="StartAllServicesWhenRollBack" BinaryKey="StartAllServicesWhenRollBackScript" VBScriptCall="" Execute="rollback" Return="check"/>
<Binary Id="StartAllServicesWhenRollBackScript" SourceFile="startInstall.vbs" />
<CustomAction Id="UninstallMysqlOdbcDriver" BinaryKey="UninstallMysqlOdbcDriverScript" VBScriptCall="" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
<Binary Id="UninstallMysqlOdbcDriverScript" SourceFile="UninstallMysqlOdbcDriver.vbs" />
```

it will rollback in the install,but not work in upgrade,another method is:

```
  <Custom Action="StartAllServicesWhenRollBack" Before="StopAllServicesa">1</Custom>
  <Custom Action="StopAllServicesa" After="InstallInitialize">1</Custom>

  <CustomAction Id="StartAllServicesWhenRollBack" BinaryKey="StartAllServicesWhenRollBackScript" VBScriptCall="" Execute="rollback" Return="check"/>
<Binary Id="StartAllServicesWhenRollBackScript" SourceFile="startInstall.vbs" />
<CustomAction Id="StopAllServicesa" BinaryKey="StopAllServicesaScript" VBScriptCall="" Execute="deferred" Return="check"/>
<Binary Id="StopAllServicesaScript" SourceFile="stopService.vbs" />
```

this method not work in upgrade,so im confuse about this,the StopAllServicesa will execute but rollback action doesnt execute,it seems the rollback action not written in the rollback script,**how can i find the rollback script in log?**

Comment: You may need to clarify the question. A major upgrade is an install and an uninstall. You haven't said where your upgrade is scheduled. You also haven't said where the upgrade failure is happening, because the upgrade install itself can fail before it removes the older product at the RemoveExistingProducts action, or the uninstall of the older product could fail and reinstall itself and rollback the upgrade. The rollback script is not in the log, but a complete verbose log of the entire upgrade has the information anyway because it's a log of the script actions.

Comment: OK,THX,it is  A major upgrade,Because the Major upgrade will uninstall the older product,so my rollback action should work in the new version install,is that right?which mean major upgrade have two stage,if i click the cancel button at  uninstall old version stage,my rollback action not work cause the older product doesnt have rollback action,but if i cancel at install new version stage,my rollback action will work,So This is my test result,So what i said is right?this is my  comprehension..i dont know right or wrong..

Comment: You still haven't said where your major upgrade is sequenced, that makes a difference. Also, the major upgrade all happens during the single progress bar (assuming you're doing a normal upgrade) so are you sure you know which stage of the upgrade is being canceled?

Comment: my MajorUpgrade Schedule is afterInstallInitialize,the upgrade fail in install,after the RemoveExistingProducts,So maybe i misunderstand the majorupgrade,i alway think it has two stage,it will uninstall product first and  install the new product,but i ignore the sequenced,which means my rollback action will take effect after the RemoveExistingProducts,and after test it work,why i have question before is caused by my search result,which always said rollback action should combine with a deferred action,Actually they can work alone,So thank you for your help.if i said some wrong,please tell meTHX

Comment: @PhilDW can you answer my next question?i also confuse about it [can i add rollback action in MajorUpgrade uninstall stage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713279/can-add-rollback-action-on-removeexistingproducts-uninstall-stage)

Answer (score 0):

If a product is being installed there is the rollback functionality so that custom actions can roll back any changes they made to the system. There isn't really an "uninstall rollback". When a product is being uninstalled and fails in some way the "rollback" is simply to re-install the product. There is no need for anything special in the way of rollback in this case. If RemoveExistingProducts fails them it simply undoes the uninstall by re-installing the product.

Without seeing the full verbose log it's impossible to diagnose exactly what's going on, but the "install new product" part of an upgrade fails then the install rolls back and call any required rollback CAs. It's no different from the user canceling an uninstall - Windows just reinstalls the product and doesn't need something like "uninstall rollback custom actions" to make it work.

Comment: THX again,So it is unnecessary to add rollback action because the product will reinstall,and i should find out the reason why the service not start,i also want to confirm  that the rollback action in my log is all belong to the new product? Before your  explaination i think part of the rollback action is belong to uninstall stage,Beside that,my restart service rollback action work when i change my MajorUpgrade Schedule to afterInstallExecute,which will install new product first and uninstall after InstallFinalize,so if an error happen before InstallFinalize,it will reinstall the old product?